# Assign order to customer if email exist

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, sales-order, onestepcheckout

If customer try to place order as guest using email, which is already register then assign  order to that register user.

Answer (score 1):

You could hook onto the event `checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after` that the order's email address, perform a look-up for customer and then set and save the customer against the order object passed to the event.

Though this would mean is someone who was not the customer guess and email address or miss-typed their email address then the order could "magic" itself onto someone else's account.

You could always do this earlier and validate the email address when saving it on the first page of the checkout and informing the user. Though this could still be seen as a security risk as it could be used as a way to get user's emails. A generic message like "Have you considered registering with our website or do you already have an account?" might work though.

Answer (score 0):

This will be easy by setting customer id field in magento sales_order table. There are some extensions which will automate such tasks. You can see one at http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/assign-order-to-customer.html